# jquery :click event

Tags: jquery

i need to bind menus dynamically based on role, thus i concatinated string with ul & li tags. i need to show the selected text in the label thus i added a click event but not fires

**Html code**

```
<div id='jqxWidget' style='height: 30px; display: none;background-color:#e8e8e8'>
    <div id='jqxMenu' style='margin-left: 20px;'></div>
</div>
```

**string binded in jqxmenu**

```
  <ul id='mainid'>
     <li><a href=#>Operations</a>
       <ul style='width: 150px;'>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1010>Booking</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1009>Manifest </a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1002>RunSheet</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1004>Delivery Updation</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=1007>Recovery</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=100>Local Manifest Branch</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=5501>Extras</a></li>
         <li><a href=default.aspx?src=2300>Bulk Import</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

For example if manifest is selected i need to show that text in a label
above click event is not fired
any suggestions

**thanks in advance**

I tried the below code for click event

```
$('#jqxMenu li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();     // Check if the li has a parent .. To prevent double firing of li     
            if ($(this).parents('li').length) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            alert($(this).html());
        });
```

click event is not fired
but when i tested it in fiddle its working fine

total jquery code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var theme = getTheme();
        $('#jqxMenu li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();     // Check if the li has a parent .. To prevent double firing of li     
            if ($(this).parents('li').length) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
            alert($(this).html());
        });
        $("#jqxMenu").css('visibility', 'visible');
        $("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ width: '600', height: '30px', theme: theme });
        $("#open").bind('change', function (event) {
            $("#jqxMenu").jqxMenu({ autoOpen: true });
        });        
        $('#jqxMenu').bind('itemclick', function ()
        { $('#selid').val($(event.args).text()); });        
    });
```

any suggestions why the click event is not fired in website
thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'itemclick' event of jqxMenu.